# How to splice wires on an Electric dog fence

Tags: electrical

I am installing an electric pet fence.  It is indicated that the perimeter wire must be able to make it around the yard to meet at both ends so it can be spliced into the twisted wire that feeds into the transmitter. The twisted wire will cancel the signal. So I get all that   My question is, is there any type of tubing I can feed through some of the live wire so it can be another dead zone.  Also, how can I splice off twisted wire to create another dead zone.  I was thinking of the running the 15feet through the crawl space since I read concrete may block the signal.   Help  P.S. I am not an electrician but one did set the transmitter into the wall.

Comment: Question is a little unclear. do you want to know how to make some sections of the electrical wire insulated so that it does not shock you when you touch it?  - also you don't want to let the "signal/energy" dissipate anywhere! thats why it basically makes a loop,- out one side of the energizer and back on the other side - if there is lots of power lost it may trigger an alarm - setting the live strand into concrete will do this. Best is to use something called HT Lead or some good insulated cable (if its a low power unit)

Comment: TJP why do you think that the 15 feet isn't good enough?  Have you tried it and determined that the signal doesn't cancel?

Answer (score 1):

To be sure I've answered your question, yes you can use electricians corrugated metal conduit.  You'd have to connect a ground wire and tie it off as close to the transmitter's (the wall socket that the perimeter wires connect to) ground as possible.  For your second question, I'd go to home depot and peruse the electrical section.  When I installed my invisible fence, I used either the crimpable ones, called a butt splice, but found that the wire rusted out and dropped the signal to ground in a rain storm, -or- the new fancy ones like the following: [AlumiConn 3-Port](http://www.homedepot.com/p/AlumiConn-3-Port-Al-Cu-Wire-Connectors-25-Pack-95125-0/204071423).  If this sounds a little "hack-ish" don't worry, if you study the electric fence's supplied manual and inferred method you'll see they are just as bad.  This is low voltage stuff, so you won't get shocked.

So,... now that your question is answered, I have to say, the conduit is overkill.  I would think that 15 feet of the twisted wire is more than sufficient.  The longer the twisted section with tighter twists the better, but my dogs never got zapped once walking out of the garage where this was installed, so I recommend trying it (testing it without the dog collar on the dog of course) and see if it is an issue before you waste lots of time and money on trying to attenuate a signal that may not be a problem in the first place.  While the electrician "hackery" of these electric fence companies may appear a little unnerving, they have definitely overcome the problem of needing "deadzones" in the fence quite well.

Comment: Direct-burial-rated (self-sealing) type splices are a good idea here.  Depending on the wire gauge on your fence, something like [this](http://www.lowes.com/pd_447115-48412-67000_0__) could be made to work well...